# How to use subprocess to invoke "/etc/init.d/tomcat6/ stop" in Python

Tags: tomcat, command, subprocess

I want to invoke /etc/init.d/tomcat6 in subprocess.
I have tried the below code, but it didn't work.

```
cmd="/etc/init.d/tomcat6/ stop"
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print stdout,stderr
```

Anyone could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
subprocess.call(['/etc/init.d/tomcat6', 'stop'])
```

or, if you really need to capture the standard output/error

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/etc/init.d/tomcat6', 'stop'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```